# How to display two table columns per row in php loop

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach, html-table

I would like to display data, two columns per row during my foreach. I would like my result to look like the following:

```
 <table>
 <tr><td>VALUE1</td><td>VALUE2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>VALUE3</td><td>VALUE4</td></tr>
 <tr><td>VALUE5</td><td>VALUE6</td></tr>
 </table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$i=0;
foreach ($x as $key=>$value)
  {
  if (fmod($i,2)) echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
  if (fmod($i,2)) echo '</tr>';
  $i++;
  }
```

this will output TR (row) each second time

ps: i haven't tested the code, so maybe you will need to add ! sign before fmod, if it doesn't output TR on first iteration, but on second iteration in the beginning...

Comment: Thank you, this works great. Yeah I had to add !fmod for the first.

Comment: @FredStevens-Smith: Instead of saying 'Does not work', why don't you elaborate a little. Why doesn't it work? Have you received an error? How could it be bettered?

Comment: Your code appears to contain a mistake; `$i++` should have been moved up one line.

Answer (score 48):

You can use `array_chunk()` to split an array of data into smaller arrays, in this case of length 2, for each row.

```
<table>
<?php foreach (array_chunk($values, 2) as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($row as $value) { ?>
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($value); ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Note that if you have an odd number of values, this will leave a final row with only one cell. If you want to add an empty cell if necessary, you could check the length of `$row` within the outer `foreach`.

Comment: Just used this on a project I was working on. Worked great!

Answer (score 1):

This would give you great table and for loop concept--

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">

<?php

     for($x=1; $x<=20; $x++)
        {
         echo "<tr>";
        for($y=1; $y<=20; $y++)
           {
          echo "<td>";
          echo $x*$y;
          echo "</td>"; 
           }
         echo "</tr>";
        }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what the OP wanted... Read the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
<?php
   $i=0;
   foreach ($x as $key=>$value)
   {
      if (!$i%2) echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
      if ($i%2) echo '</tr>';
      $i++;
   }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: it should =   if ($i%2 == 0) echo '<tr>';