# How to display two table columns per row in Angular 2 loop (Angular2 equivalent of PHP's array_chunk)

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I achieve the following with Angular 2?

I would like to display data, two columns per row during my foreach. I would like my result to look like the following:

```
<table>
<tr><td>VALUE1</td><td>VALUE2</td></tr>
<tr><td>VALUE3</td><td>VALUE4</td></tr>
<tr><td>VALUE5</td><td>VALUE6</td></tr>
</table>
```

[image: Table: each row has 2 array items]
[image]

Similar question: [How to display two table columns per row in php loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793716/how-to-display-two-table-columns-per-row-in-php-loop)

Plunker with basic idea: https://plnkr.co/edit/LuEYfK?p=preview

Comment: why downvoting?

Comment: I suppose someone didn't read you question entirely. I was about to downvote as well, but read it, and gave you an upvote a while ago, so back to zero ;) Seems people aren't reading thoroughly, I suspect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/umL80bh0WKr8aPEueCxZ?p=preview

You can create pipe to get pairs values:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'pairs' })
export class PairsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array) {
    return array.reduce((result, item, index) => (
      index % 2 ? result : [...result, [item, array[index + 1]]]
    ), []);
  }
}
```

add pipe to Module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App , PairsPipe],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

and use in *ngFor:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of data | pairs">
```

Comment: Nice but you loose databinding with the original array in the process as you can see here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/vbes9q8gj72N9exdSHOu?p=preview

Comment: What if i want to take N number of columns?

Comment: @SteamFire: So mark it as impure: https://plnkr.co/edit/UNsOUqlStZxcqvull6jW?p=preview  [or https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873678]

Comment: I don't understand?

Answer (score 3):

You can use *ngFor for loop:

```
let data = [{value:'VALUE1'}, {value:'VALUE2'}, {id: 3, value:'VALUE3'},{value:'VALUE4'}];

<table>
 <div *ngFor="let item of data | let isEven = even;let i = index;let isLast= last">
 <tr *ngIf="isEven & !isLast">
   <td>item1 value: {{data[i].value}}</td>
   <td>item2 value: {{data[i + 1].value}}</td>   
   </tr>
 </div>
</table>
```

i am not sure if this is what you mean hope its helping you.

Good Luck

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Your answer gives for each item, 1 column in a single row. I want 2 columns in a single row. I'd like to consume 2 items from array for each <TR>

Comment: You just need to use logic with index and check it's mod. Look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

In ngRepeat you have a variable to track if the iteration is odd or even ($odd and $even). In your case, check, if even, you close it (TR tag) and open a new one.

Comment: @Marco This is Angular 2 ;)

Comment: I a Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/LuEYfK?p=preview based off your idea. It mostly works, but it generates invalid HTML markupt due to the DIV being inside a TABLE.

Comment: angular 2 can't parsing element(<tr>) with `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` together...

Answer (score 1):

Base on @YairTawil answer, I create a pipe to display 3 item per page like below.

This way I implement in my project, I share for whom concern.

Pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'pairs'
})
export class PairsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array) {
    return array.reduce((result, item, index) => (
      index % 3 ? result : [...result, [item, array[index + 1], array[index + 2]]]
    ), []);
  }
}
```

TS code

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  data = {
    DepartmentFees: [
      { Name: "컴포넌트", Value: 1480.0 },
      { Name: "기판", Value: 1758.0 },
      { Name: "모듈", Value: 1617.0 },
      { Name: "렌즈", Value: 1447.0 },
      { Name: "테스트", Value: 1345.0 },
      { Name: "광케이블", Value: 1365.0 }
    ]
  };
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data.DepartmentFees | pairs">
    <div class="d-flex mt-1">
        <div class="flex-fill pl-3 pr-3">
            <div class="text-left divider_card_title">{{item[0].Name}}</div>
            <div class="text-right value_unit mt-1">억원</div>
            <h3 class="text-right mt-2">{{item[0].Value}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-fill pl-3 pr-3">
            <div class="text-left divider_card_title">{{item[1].Name}}</div>
            <div class="text-right value_unit mt-1">억원</div>
            <h3 class="text-right mt-2">{{item[1].Value}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-fill pl-3 pr-3">
            <div class="text-left divider_card_title">{{item[2].Name}}</div>
            <div class="text-right value_unit mt-1">억원</div>
            <h3 class="text-right mt-2">{{item[2].Value}}</h3>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-divider mt-2"></div>
</div>
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-display-3item-row