# Angular 6 Transform rows to multiple columns

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

I'm working on an application and I'm trying to format the report links how I want them. Ideally, there should be 3 or 4 rows, and at least 6 columns wide. I know I have to use a pipe to help with the formatting, I just cannot get the logic down. I tried using the pipe from [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597438/how-to-display-two-table-columns-per-row-in-angular-2-loop-angular2-equivalent) angular answer, however, it does not work (no rows will show).

Here is a code sample of my Angular 6 code:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let report of annualReports">
    <td><a href="#">{{ report.rptDisplayName }}</a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the pipe:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'pairs' })
export class PairsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any) {
    return value.filter((v, i) => i % 2 == 0).map((v, i) => [value[i * 2], value[i * 2 + 1]])
  } 
}
```

Comment: did you apply 'pairs' in the HTML code? Also, using css grid or bootstrap might be easy to achieve the same effect.

Comment: when I change it to | pairs, I get no results. However, I can breakpoint the pipe and see it's being called, just nothing is returned and I'm not 100% sure how to change the map to have the correct formula.

Comment: thanks, the answer was css-grid. if you want to post an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: cool, will do that. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you apply 'pairs' in the HTML code? Also, using CSS Grid or bootstrap might be easy to achieve the same effect.

Comment: The answer here was utilizing a css-grid layout to perform what I needed!